# AddType / AddHandler Not Working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm working on a mac running OS X Lion and PHP 5.3.6 and have tried both `AddType`, `AddHander`, and `AllowOverride` has been set to `ALL` in the httpd.conf; however, the PHP codes in HTML/JS/CSS files are still parsed as text. Files ending with .php are all good. I'm now getting really desperate after hours of googling.

Here are the contents of my `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .js .css 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .js .css 

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .js .css 
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php.html .js .css
```

Answer (score 1):

If your site is stored in your user's `Sites` folder (i.e. `/Users/username/Sites/`) then you also need to set `AllowOveride` in the user-specific configuration file in `/etc/apache2/users/username.conf`. After making the change restart apache by disabling and re-enabling Web Sharing in the Sharing preference pane.

Answer (score 0):

The AddType procedure (at least on **Mac OS X Server**) requires:

1. one and only extension per line
2. no dots before the extension

   `AddType application/x-httpd-php php`

Have a look at `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` for running examples.

*(You should also remove the AddHandler procedures.)*

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem and fixed with:

```
<Files ~ "\.(gif|htm|txt|css|jpg|png)$">
       SetHandler default-handler
</Files>
```